# Difficulty Clicking a Specific Button in Firefox Using Watir

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I've been struggling with this for the past few hours. There's a certain button on a page that I'm trying to get the script to click, but I keep getting [this error](http://imgur.com/kgyLwSd&AcLOmFR#1).

[Here is the HTML of the button I'm trying to click on.](http://imgur.com/kgyLwSd&AcLOmFR#0)

The code I'm using to try and click on it looks like:

```
$browser.button(:name => 'Add and Continue').click
```

For the attribute, I've also tried text. I even tried using the ID but that didn't work, which is for the best since it changes frequently. I've also made sure that it isn't within a frame.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, you should add any code (i.e. the html) directly into the question

Comment: @EggVans Sorry about that, I'll go ahead and do that when I get in tomorrow.

Comment: Is that button visible on the page?  It appears that's in a <div> tag with style="display: none;".

Comment: @orde Yeah, I'm not sure why it's saying that. The button is visible and clickable.

Comment: Are you sure you actually tried `$browser.button(:text => 'Add and Continue').click`? Based on the exception, I am guessing you actually tried `$browser.button(:text => ' Add and Continue').click` The space at the start would cause the element to not be located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the text property you are looking for, but it is not matching because of the image content which is also in the text of the button. You should probably use a regular expression along the lines of

```
$browser.button(:text => /Add and Continue/).click
```

Comment: I think beyond the image content, the leading and trailing spaces that seem to be a part of the button text (in the image provided by @Civil) are what is preventing this from working. I am betting the regex you suggested above for the button text will take care of this.